# Rewriting code in a repository at heroku each time I push to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have an instance at heroku where I push the different branches of the same project for testing. Since the branches are different (although they are created off the main, develop branch) and it's only for testing, whenever I push to it I'd like that new "push" completely rewrite code there without any merging, conflicts, etc. In other worlds, I'd like kind of truncate (or recreate) my repository at heroku each time before pushing.

Is it possible?

Comment: did my answer work for you Alex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `git push heroku master --force` or if you would like to deploy a specific branch, then `git push heroku <branchname>:master --force`